# Can not publish Blazor wasm to azure anymore

Tags: azure, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly

i just wanted to publish my changes to my .Net6 blazor wasm app to azure to update it like i did a dozen times. Since yesterday that does not work anymore. I can build and run it locally with no problem but when I try to publish it, I get a window telling me:

> Publish has encountered an error. Build failed. Check the Output
> window for more details.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpE865.tmp"

Content of that file:

> 16.06.2022 08:20:08 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException:
> Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.    --- End of
> inner exception stack trace ---
> ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed.
> Check the Output window for more details.<---
>
> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed.
> Check the Output window for more details.
>
> ===================

Console Output:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.400-preview.22301.10\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets(614,5): Error MSB6006: "dotnet.exe" exited with code 1.

Tried fetching older versions of the code that I successfully published a few days ago. Still does not work. My coworker can still publish the same code.

**But I can publish my API Backend...so this error seems to be related to blazor wasm.**

Tried this with the latest release of VS 2022 and just gave the preview version a try - no luck.

I've also done a repair installation of the .Net 6 SDK.

Edit: I've tried to publish my project to a folder and got the same error. So no relation to azure. Then I've created a new blank Blazor app...I can publish this one to a folder with no error. So my project is somehow broken...but even older code can't be published. This is so odd...

Comment: Are you following any document ?

Comment: What document do you mean?

Comment: Please refer [.NET Hot Reload updates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-4/#net-hot-reload-updates)        - [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjAPy.png)

Comment: When you publish from VS it should be possible to find that Build error somewhere.

Comment: And why are you on 6.0.400-preview ?  What version does your coworker use?

Comment: I had this with vs 2022 when it was new. Didn't figured out. It pushed me to abandone this vs publish feature and use CI/CD solution. I know it's not answer to your question, but I strongly recommend that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I couldn't find much about this error. The preview is in there because I've also tried it with the preview version of VS 2022. With the release version I get the same error but it does use the release version of the SDK (6.0.301). In the output window of my coworker I can see 6.0.300 ... interesting. I guess it is because my VS is a little more up to date. But there where no update since it worked last time.

Comment: @Alamakanambra Oh okay. I am fairly new to all that cloud and web stuff. Can you explain a little further what you are doing now to publish your apps on azure?

Comment: This is far OT for this question. For example this: https://blazorhelpwebsite.com/ViewBlogPost/9 may help you, but there is a lot of eventualities. Contact me, if you need any help

Comment: Thanks a lot. No matter if I get this to work again or not, I will definitely set up something like that.

Comment: Related GitHub issues: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42262 and https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26061

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@XSharp is correct.
We had same issue started occurring yesterday.
We were using version '6.0.x' of DotNet which seems to have started using version '6.0.301' that seems to be causing this issue.  Force it to use the previous version '6.0.106' instead

Just add the following at the top of your tasks in your YAML

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
     packageType: 'sdk'
     version: '6.0.106'
```

Looks like someone has reported it as an issue when having a blank space in your project path: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7548

Comment: OMG...Yes there was 1 Space in the path...removed it and worked fine. Lost more than a day of work due to this.
Still don't know why this suddenly stopped working. As someone in that github issue stated, this issue was already present in 17.2.3 which I had...I dont know...for a week or so.

I'll think twice now before doing a VS update on the first day it appears...

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Same issue here, had a few files with spaces in them as well as an unused nuget package generating dlls with spaces in the filenames. Would have been impossible to find the reason going off of the error message itself and without explicitly checking all the generated files for spaces in the build output...

Answer (score 8):

Same issue for me. Publish stopped working after the latest VS update.
Removing blanks in path resolved it

Comment: Removing whitespace in the path solved my problem too.

Comment: To be clear, I had to remove all spaces in the path to the solution, so in the parent directories. This was a common issue in VS 2015 and Lightswitch projects if anyone remembers them ;)

Comment: Removing whitespace and removing the "bin" and "obj" directories fixed this for me too

Comment: I've had it happen with no spaces in the path.

Answer (score 2):

I kept getting error "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Blazor WebAssembly.6_0.targets(614,5): error MSB6006".
I can confirm once I removed spaces (my directory to mydirectory) on the build environment, the blazor build was successful.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem off-and-on for more than a year. Sometimes it seems to be caused by a Visual Studio update and sometimes a dependency (nuget) update, but sometimes it seems spontaneous; I can't seem to figure out the real cause. This time I tried removing spaces from the path, but that did not work.

I got it to publish again after (1) removing spaces from the path, (2) deleting the publish profiles, (3) deleting the hidden ".vs" folder from the solution directory, (4) running "Clean Solution" in VS, (5) deleting all "bin" and "obj" folders from the solution tree, (6) re-importing the publish profile, building, and publishing.  I wish I knew which of those really affected the problem, or better yet, I wish MS would fix this bug.

Comment: Still happening - definitely related to Visual Studio update or nuget update.  I'll do those separately next time to further isolate which one it is.   I have no spaces in the project path.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the SDK in the YAML of the pipeline fixed the issue for us.

In UseDotNet@2 task:

Changed : version: '6.0.x'
To : version: '6.0.106'

It was working before so it seems like something has changed in the hosts.